# Appending dataset in Carto?

Tags: carto

Is there a way to add rows to an existing dataset while importing in a table?

I've have tried inserting directly from an existing dataset but get an issue withe cartodb_id already existing.

Comment: can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, I highly recommend taking [this onboarding tour](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour). Among other things, you learn how to ask questions. As requested by @Cushen, we will need to know what you have tried, what errors are you getting and so on.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following type of INSERT query; specifying the source and target column for the insert.

This way you can ***exclude cartodb_id*** (which is an auto incremented primary key):

```
INSERT INTO existing_table 
(columna, columnb,   columnc)
SELECT 
columna, columnb,   columnc 
FROM new_table;"
```

To help you out and save time you can get a comma separated list of field names using the following:

```
SELECT string_agg(column_name, ', ')
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE table_name = 'existing_table '
```

This will return something like this, which you can paste into the insert query:

***cartodb_id, columna, columnb, columnc, the_geom, the_geom_webmercator***

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned I was trying to use the sql api as I'm on the carto engine plan.

Comment: @Cushen's answer is also valid if you are using the SQL API. But bear in mind that you will need to add your API Key as parameter in order to modify a table. More info [in CARTO docs](https://carto.com/developers/auth-api/).

Comment: Awesome, good to hear, if you accept the answer you'll let others know that this is the right solution :D